# list all module methods and attributes as a list of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was trying to dive in python and evaluating some of the builtin functions.
The dir function returns a string list containing the names of all attributes of the given module.
Because of that if I run the following code segment, I get an empty list:

```
import string
[x for x in dir(string) if callable(x) ]
```

Is There other functions or other ways, that I can combine with `dir(string)` for getting a list of Objects instead of row strings?

my goal is to do something like:

```
import string
[ x for x in ***(dir(string)) if callable(x) ]
```

and not something like the example in [dive in python book](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html#apihelper.divein)

```
 methodList = [method for method in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, method))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `dir()` returns a list of **strings**:

```
>>> import string
>>> dir(string)
['Formatter', 'Template', '_ChainMap', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_re', '_string', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'whitespace']
```

String values are not callable; these are not the actual attribute values, they are the names.

If you wanted to to test those names as attributes on the `string` module, you'd have to use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), or use the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to get the `strings` namespace as a dictionary:

```
>>> getattr(string, 'Formatter')
<class 'string.Formatter'>
>>> callable(getattr(string, 'Formatter'))
True
>>> [name for name in dir(string) if callable(getattr(string, name))]
['Formatter', 'Template', '_ChainMap', '_TemplateMetaclass', 'capwords']
>>> [name for name, obj in vars(string).items() if callable(obj)]
['capwords', '_ChainMap', '_TemplateMetaclass', 'Template', 'Formatter']
```

The order differs here because [dictionaries are unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary) and `dir()` always sorts the return value. For *modules*, `dir(module)` simply returns `sorted(vars(module))`.

If you wanted the callable objects themselves and not the names, just filter the *values* of the `vars()` dictionary:

```
[obj for obj in vars(string).values() if callable(obj)]
```

Comment: I didn't link it here, no, but I did consider linking it. My apologies, I did think you had read it. Again, comments are ephemeral. Had you been critical of my post I would not have touched the comments (at most I'd have asked another mod to look at them). I'll ask another to take a look if they feel I was too quick to clean up here. Thing is, if I *don't* clean up the comments below my own posts when I see them as obsolete, then it can take a long time before they *are*. I'm just tidying up after myself here.

Comment: Thanks, sounds all reasonable.  No need for another mod to take a look.  I think it was mostly the timinig that bothered me.

Comment: I updated the question, it was bad formulate. Have you an Idea?

Comment: @MohamedEl: there you go.

Answer (score -1):

`callable(x)` checks is `x` is an object that has a `__call__()` method. In your case, it doesn't, that's why the comprehension is returning an empty list